# How to do a conditional over map function react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to loop over some data with conditionals however I am getting a parsing error with my conditional statement.

```
 const unitTests = unitTestTemplates.map((item) => 
  
  if (item.typical_dq_domain){
    console.log('hello')
  }
  
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map callback needs a function body, i.e. `.map(item => { ... })` if it isn't implicitly returning a value. `if (...)` isn't a valid return value so a function body is required.

```
const unitTests = unitTestTemplates.map((item) => {
  if (item.typical_dq_domain) {
    console.log('hello')
  }

  ...
  // return some value for mapping
})
```